# "initialPlaybackTime" of "MPMoviePlayerController" is not working

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I am trying to play a movie with MPMovieplayercontroller. Everything is fine except "**initialPlaybackTime**". Instead of starting to play from the given seconds, the player plays from the beginning.

How to make "initialPlaybackTime" to work?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *moviePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"02_Skater" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] ;
    // video player
    playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.contentURL = url;
    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 300);

    playerViewController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    playerViewController.initialPlaybackTime = 3;
    playerViewController.endPlaybackTime = 4;
    playerViewController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [playerViewController prepareToPlay];


    [playerViewController play];
    [[self view] addSubview: [playerViewController view]];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Any input from anyone?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Apple Documentation, you can read that:

"For video-on-demand content, playback starts at the nearest segment boundary to the provided time."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. True, but it always starts "zero time" irrespective of whatever the value i set for "initialPlaybackTime".

Comment: What does VOD have to do with playing a static MP4 video file?

Answer (score 0):

New Updates after iOS 8.4 are having these issues and still these bugs are alive in new iOS 9.0

Currently i have found a workaround that's still incomplete because you are still not able to set your end time of video. some how this solution can able you to set "initialPlaybackTime"

First add an observer to your mediaPLayer

```
//Add Observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:mediaPlayerController];
```

and Write this Method for Notification

```
BOOL playbackDurationSet=NO;
-(void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification{
    MPMoviePlayerController* player = (MPMoviePlayerController*)notification.object;

    switch ( player.playbackState ) {
        case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying:

            if(!playbackDurationSet){
                [mediaPlayerController setCurrentPlaybackTime:player.initialPlaybackTime];
                playbackDurationSet=YES;
            }
            break;

         default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)resetPlayerDurationVar{
    playbackDurationSet=NO;
}
```